# Making semicolons optional for some rules while keeping the trailing semicolon optional?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I am trying to make semicolons optional for certain rules while keeping the last semicolon optional. Currently we have something like

```
A: 'A';
B: 'B';
C: 'B';
SEMICOLON: ';';

exprs : expr (SEMICOLON expr)* SEMICOLON?;

expr : A | B | C
```

for parsing input like

```
A;
C;
B
```

However now we want the semicolon to optional for 'A'. Which would mean parsing something like

```
A
C;
B
```

The part that I am having issues with is making the semicolon optional for A while still allowing the last semicolon to be optional. Is there a nice way to do this or should I just make the last semicolon required?

(Couldn't think of a decent title so feel free to change it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the SEMICOLON symbol to expr (semantically it belongs to that anyway).

```
expr:
    A SEMICOLON?
    | (B | C) {LA(1) != EOF}? SEMICOLON
;

exprs:
    expr+
;
```

Update: changed the B and C branch to use a lookahead to decide.

Comment: That would make SEMICOLON required on the last line though if it ends in C. So B and C require a semicolon if they are not the last line.

Comment: Is there a way to end the expr+ match when there isn't a SEMICOLON? Checking for EOF isn't going to work for my case because there will be more tokens after exprs.

Comment: You need to define then how your exprs are terminated. There must be a condition that can be used, especially with optional end terminators (which often make things for a parser harder). If all fails you could use a semantic predicate to check if neither A nor B nor C is following.

Comment: Ya this will probably need a semantic predicate. It is just a matter of how exactly to do it. I want to do something like the 'Loops' section here http://meri-stuff.blogspot.com/2012/12/antlr-semantic-predicates.html. However ({false}?=> expr)* is not generating a break. Instead it just throws a FailedPredicateException.

Comment: I can only repeat: you need a condition that exactly specifies when exprs is finished. This must be a token so you can use this in the predicate to either check for a semicolon or this token. I used EOF above but any other token does as well. Can the first token from whatever might follow exprs be used (e.g. a closing parenthesis)? You can have more than one token (e.g. {LA(1) == EOF || LA(1) == ')')? ... etc.